# Convert Delphi reference to procedure C++ Builder

Tags: c++, delphi, c++builder

i need little help here convert delphi to c++ builder
almost finish to convert but find one problem

delphi file CloudPopulator.pas

```
TTransferJobVisitor = reference to procedure(const Job: TCloudTransferJob);

TCloudTransferManager = class
  private
  public
    procedure ForEachJob(AVisitor: TTransferJobVisitor);
  end;
```

usage script CloudExplorerUI.pas

```
TCloudTransferManager.Instance.ForEachJob(
            procedure(const Job: TCloudTransferJob)
            begin
              if Job.JobType = tjtUPLOAD then
                TransferGrid.Cells[0,I] := 'UPLOAD'
              else
                TransferGrid.Cells[0,I] := 'DOWNLOAD';
            end);
```

i have convert to c++ builder :

CloudPopulator.h

```
typedef void __fastcall (* TTransferJobVisitor)(const TCloudTransferJob* Job);

class TCloudTransferManager: public System::TObject
{
  private:          
  public:
      void __fastcall ForEachJob(TTransferJobVisitor AVisitor);  
};
```

how to write this part on c++ builder

i have made something like this

```
struct MyAVisitor
{
    TCloudUIForm* form;
    MyAVisitor(TCloudUIForm *_form) : form(_form) {}
    void operator()(const TCloudTransferJob* Job)
    {
        if (Job->JobType == tjtUPLOAD)
            form->TransferGrid->Cells[0][0] = L"UPLOAD";
        else
            form->TransferGrid->Cells[0][0] = L"DOWNLOAD";
    }
};
```

but still not sure to make

```
typedef TMethodRef<TCloudTransferJob, MyAVisitor, void> MyMethRef;
```

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/How_to_Handle_Delphi_Anonymous_Methods_in_C%2B%2B

Comment: @MBo thnx for repply, i have make base on your link, but still need help to typedef declare (i have update question)

Comment: Read the link, and do what it says.